# Connection refused ESP32

Tags: c++, c

I have project using GSR sensor with ESP32. Data from ESP32 is saved in database.

But, in my code I have an error. When using static IP, `HTTPClient.begin()` always returns connection refused.

I've seen this question asked a few times but never got a good answer.

```cpp
#include <ssl_client.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

/* Konfigurasi pada SSID dan Password Wifi */
const char* ssid     = "AndroidAP";         
const char* password = "stayC00L";  

/* Konfigurasi koneksi ke server */
char server[] = "192.168.43.111";     // Ganti dengan IP Address komputer aplikasi 
int port = 81;

/*konfigurasi*/
const int GSR = 32;
float sensorValue = 0;
float gsr_average = 0;

IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 43, 113);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8); // Google DNS

WiFiClient client;
void setup() {
  
  USE_SERIAL.begin(9600);         // Baudrate/kec. komunikasi pengiriman data ke serial terminal
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);      
  USE_SERIAL.print("Terhubung ke ");
  USE_SERIAL.print(ssid);

  WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, dns);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    USE_SERIAL.print('.');
  }

  USE_SERIAL.print('\n');
  USE_SERIAL.println("Identitas ESP-32");  
  USE_SERIAL.print("IP Address:\t");
  USE_SERIAL.println(WiFi.localIP());         // IP Address ESP-32  

  USE_SERIAL.print('\n');
  USE_SERIAL.println("Identitas Web Server");
  USE_SERIAL.println("IP Address:");
  USE_SERIAL.print(server);
  USE_SERIAL.print("\tport:\t");
  USE_SERIAL.print(port);
}


void loop() {
  
    long sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)           //Average the 10 measurements to remove the glitch
    {
      sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
      sum += sensorValue;
      delay(100);
    }
    gsr_average = sum/10;
    USE_SERIAL.println(gsr_average);

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    //URL target untuk menyimpan data sensor GSR ke database
    String url = "http://192.168.43.111:81/";
    url += "TA/Monitoring/simpan/";
    url += String(gsr_average);

    HTTPClient http;
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    http.begin(url);
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
    
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    if(httpCode > 0) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", 
        httpCode);
      
         if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
         }
      } else {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", 
        http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      } 
      http.end();
   }
}
```

And the error is

> connection refused

Please help me. What should I do??

Comment: Check status of server http port should be open and accessible.

Comment: I did it. and the http port server is open

Comment: The error you are getting indicated that the server did not accept the connection, it actually actively refused it. Check your server, maybe try accessing it from another computer on the network, and try again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to delete :

```
IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 43, 113);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8); // Google DNS
```

and :

```
WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, dns);
```

After this modification it works perfectly for me.

[image: post response 200]

Comment: Besides, I think you should put 115200 rate in bits per second instead of 9600 because it is an esp32, not an Arduino.

Comment: This will put the board in dhcp, not a solution